# Javascript grouping by data from data and returning array of objects

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have 100 objects of data within an array that looks like this:

```
{
  id: "1",
  date: "2022/01/01",
  name: "John",
},
{
  id: "2",
  date: "2022/01/02",
  name: "Chris",
},
```

I am trying to return an array of objects by date that also returns the names.

For example:

```
[
 {
  date: "2022/01/01",
  names: ["John", "Steve"...]
 },
 {
  date: "2022/01/02",
  names: ["Chris", "Rob"...]
 },
]
```

I have tried using the reduce method:

```
 const groupedByDate = () =>
    data.reduce((itemsIterated, { date, name }) => {
      if (!itemsIterated[date]) {
        itemsIterated[date] = {
          date,
          names: [],
        };
      }
      itemsIterated[date].names.push(name);
      return itemsIterated;
    }, []);
```

The issue is this gives me array with a key of the date and then the object with date/names but I don't know how to return just the array of objects by date.

Comment: your accumulator (empty array in last line) needs to be an empty object `{}`. Now the `groupedByDate()` will return an object grouped by date. To get the values array of the object. use `Object.values(groupedByDate())`

Answer (score 0):

The function `groupedByDate` would return an object like this -

```js
const result = {
  '2022/01/01': {
    date: "2022/01/01",
    names: ["John", "Steve"...]
  },
  '2022/01/02': {
    date: "2022/01/02",
    names: ["Chris", "Rob"...]
  },
}
```

However, to retrieve it in the format you need, you would need to make use of `Object.values()`.

```js
Object.values(result);
/*
[
 {
  date: "2022/01/01",
  names: ["John", "Steve"...]
 },
 {
  date: "2022/01/02",
  names: ["Chris", "Rob"...]
 },
]
*/
```

**NOTE**

- To learn more about `Object.values()` - [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values)
- `reduce`'s second parameter is the initial value of the accumulator. Here, we would need to use `{}` instead of `[]` in the `groupedByDate` function.